# Is there a way to see Rails very old bash history from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

TBH I'm looking for a stack trace that happened about four weeks ago. Its an error that I need to track down just for providing some proof to the businessmen.

I've discovered that I can call `history`, but that doesn't go back as far as I need it to. Is there a log for this?

`log/development.log` was cleaned out about a week after the error occurred.

Comment: I wonder what TBH means.

Comment: "To be honest", I guess.